# wp_redirect rendering the page in network tab but not redirecting from current url

Tags: php, wordpress

I call the method to redirect from a file like this:

```
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'user.php');
$user = new User();
$user->signInUser($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
```

In the user.php file;

```
public function signInUser()
{
    $url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/dashboard.php';
    //http://localhost/myproject/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/templates/dashboard.php

    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}
```

The dashboard page is accessed (network tab), but it's not redirecting from current url.

I tried, `header('Location: http://google.com');exit;`

Not working either.
How can I change redirect correctly?

[image]

Ajax (redirection not working either):

```
$(function() {

    //registration form
    $('#registration').submit(function() {

        var $inputs = $('#registration :input');
        var values = {};
        $inputs.each(function() {
            values[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });

        jQuery.ajax({

              url: "http://localhost/myproject/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=registration",
              method: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              'data': values
          }).success(function(data) {

            $(location).attr('href',
                'http://localhost/myproject/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/templates/dashboard.php');
          });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: When do you call this lines : `require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'user.php');
$user = new User();
$user->signInUser($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);` ? Is your script call in ajax ? if yes, your wp_redirect redirect only your ajax script. In this case the only way to redirect your page is to redirect your page in javascript on ajax success. Can you add a screenshot of your network tab ?

Comment: When do you call this lines : `require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'user.php');
$user = new User();
$user->signInUser($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);` ? Is your script call in ajax ? if yes, your wp_redirect redirect only your ajax script. In this case the only way to redirect your page is to redirect your page in javascript on ajax success

Comment: @Fabien, I redirect when registration form is submitted. The submittion is handled via ajax. However, the jquery redirection returns the same result in network tab and not redirecting.